# Stop AudioRecord object of another application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, audio-recording, audiorecord

In my android application, i am recording incoming and outgoing calls through `AudioRecord`. Now what happens is that i have another call recording application which does the same function. So i am getting following exception When i try to initialize AudioRecord object.

```
AudioRecord : Could not get audio input for record source 4
E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
```

I want that every call should be recorded through my application only. If `AudioRecord` object is initialized through another application then is there any way to release that object and start recording from my application?

Comment: Hopefully not. One app should not be able to interfere with another app that way. If you are the author of both apps, you are welcome to create your own negotiation protocol to determine which should be doing the recording.

Comment: In that case, can i do something by which my application could be the first one to receive broadcast whenever i get/do any call?

Comment: You cannot guarantee that you will get in first.